# SVG - Line becomes thicker as I rotate it

Tags: html, css, svg

I need multiple straight lines, and I have set the `stroke-width` to 4, but when I try to rotate them, the lines get thicker. Also when I try to set a negative value, for example `<path d="M0 -10 20 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="red"></path>` the line almost completely dissapears

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="50">
   <path d="M0 10 40 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="red"></path>
   <path d="M40 0 80 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="blue"></path>
   <path d="M80 0 120 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="green"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: because the green and blue have half their stroke outside that's why you think the red is thicker. Add `overflow: visible;` to SVG to notice this

Comment: @TemaniAfif This helped me. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As said **@Temani Afif** half the width of the line goes beyond the border of the canvas of the SVG
Look please, I showed the borders of the canvas of the SVG with a gray line

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="50" style="border:1px solid gray;">
   <path d="M0 10 40 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="red"></path>
   <path d="M40 0 80 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="blue"></path>
   <path d="M80 0 120 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="green"></path>
</svg>
```

You can solve this problem by adding a `viewBox` and moving down the whole picture by adding the value -10 to the viewBox parameter

By setting the width and height of the SVG canvas as a percentage, you make your application responsive

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 -10 150 50" style="border:1px solid gray;">
   <path d="M0 10 40 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="red"></path>
   <path d="M40 0 80 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="blue"></path>
   <path d="M80 0 120 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="green"></path>
</svg>
```

You can also move the whole picture down 10 pixels with the command [transform="translate(0 10)"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 150 50" style="border:1px solid gray;">
  <g transform="translate(0 10)">
  <path d="M0 10 40 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="red"></path>
   <path d="M40 0 80 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="blue"></path>
   <path d="M80 0 120 0" stroke-width="4" stroke="green"></path>
   </g>
</svg>
```